# Where can I get Tectonic Plate Shape Files

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I have downloaded the shape files from [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=357b0e32423f43cebf9f844ae70f7d1c) but the shape files will not load correctly in any shape file viewer I have.

Does anyone know of any other shape file that contains the tectonic plates?

Comment: They open fine for me on [QGIS 2.0](http://www.qgis.org/)

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded QGis (It looks great, first time for me) and Did a Check geometry Validity and it had 141 Errors. Guess this is what is causing issues with that file. I'm not a Qgis user, so any suggestions welcome on resolving the errors

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using QGis with the following steps:

1. Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Check Geometry Validity
2. Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Simplify Geometry
3. Saved as a new Shape File

It loaded just fine after this